# hustory.pushState back/forward/refresh buttons not working

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, back, pushstate

I'm working on a little custom rss reader (http://richbray.me/glint/) with two different categories – 'games' & 'tech'.

As I'm only updating one line of code between categories - [ $('#feed').rssfeed('http://www.rssmix.com/u/3831482/rss.xml', {limit: 50}); ] - I wanted to use the HTML5 history API to change it instead of making a whole new page. I've got it to work however the refresh, back and forward buttons don't update the page.

Here's the code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#feed').rssfeed('http://www.rssmix.com/u/3831482/rss.xml', {limit: 50});
        history.pushState(null, null, 'games');
    });

    $('.tech').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#feed').rssfeed('http://www.rssmix.com/u/3833245/rss.xml', {limit: 50});
        $('title').append('Tech');
        history.pushState(null, null, 'tech');
    });
```

I would really appreciate it if you guys let me know where I'm going wrong. Thanks

Comment: You're falling over at the same point I did when I did pushState stuff. The URL that the user refreshes on, in your case "tech", needs to exist on the server. Pushstate uses virtual URLs that exist only on the client. So, you can either use hash based navigation or create a new page for 'tech'!

Comment: Thanks. Went with the hash based navigation in the end.